# How to run code every 60sec in Android

Tags: java, android, android-thread

In my application I want run code **every 60sec** and this my code for get data from server.
For this I write below codes.
But **after 60sec** when run code, show me **ForceClose** error and show below message in `logCat`.

Show me error for my views into my fragment!

**My codes :**

```
public class MainReminderFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.mainExplore_noExploreTxt)
    TextView mainExplore_noExploreTxt;
    @BindView(R.id.newsPageLoadLay)
    RelativeLayout newsPageLoadLay;
    @BindView(R.id.toolbarTitleTxt)
    TextView toolbarTitleTxt;
    private Context context;
    public List<Datum> model = new ArrayList<>();
    public ReminderAdapter reminderAdapter;
    private SharedPrefrencesHandler prefrencesHandler;
    private String token = "";
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private InterfaceApi api;
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    public ProgressBar mainExplore_progressBar;
    public RecyclerView mainExplore_recyclerView;

    public MainReminderFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_reminder, container, false);
        //Initialize
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        context = getActivity();
        prefrencesHandler = new SharedPrefrencesHandler(context);
        reminderAdapter = new ReminderAdapter(context, model);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        mainExplore_progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.mainExplore_progressBar);
        mainExplore_recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.mainExplore_recyclerView);
        isRunning = true;
        mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
        //Toolbar name
        toolbarTitleTxt.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.reminder));
        //RecyclerView
        mainExplore_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mainExplore_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        //Get token
        token = prefrencesHandler.getFromShared(SharedPrefrencesKeys.TOKEN.name());

        //Get data
        getData();
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            while (true) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                }
                                if (isRunning) {
                                    getData();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });
        }
        return view;
    }

    //SendData method
    private SerialReminderListSendData sendData(int page) {
        SerialReminderListSendData listSendData = new SerialReminderListSendData();
        listSendData.setPageIndex(page);
        listSendData.setPageSize(200);

        return listSendData;
    }

    //Get data
    private void getData() {
        Call<SerialReminderListResponse> call = api.getListSerialReminder(token, "2", sendData(1));

        mainExplore_progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<SerialReminderListResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SerialReminderListResponse> call, Response<SerialReminderListResponse> response) {
                if (response.body().getData() != null && response.body().getStatusCode() != 401
                        && response.body().getStatusCode() != 402) {
                    if (response.body().getData().size() > 0) {
                        model.clear();
                        model.addAll(response.body().getData());
                        reminderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mainExplore_recyclerView.setAdapter(reminderAdapter);
                        //Gone no explore
                        mainExplore_noExploreTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        mainExplore_noExploreTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mainExplore_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                mainExplore_progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SerialReminderListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                mainExplore_progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Error Message in logCat :**

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7130)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5284)
at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:13615)
at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13579)
at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:11422)
at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:8014)
at com.app.test.Fragments.MainPageFrags.MainReminderFragment.getData(MainReminderFragment.java:182)
at com.app.test.Fragments.MainPageFrags.MainReminderFragment.access$100(MainReminderFragment.java:47)
at com.app.test.Fragments.MainPageFrags.MainReminderFragment$1$1.run(MainReminderFragment.java:142)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

How can I fix it? please help me

Comment: Have you tried using handlers?

Comment: don't use Thread.sleep on UI thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            float i;
            try {
                for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            getData();
                        }
                    });
                    sleep(6000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you try to change the properties of an `View` you can only do that from the `Thread` which created it in the first place. And that is the main Thread / UI Thread. So for for example if you call

`mainExplore_noExploreTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

you have to call it from the main thread. There is an utility method for that which is `runOnUiThread`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainExplore_noExploreTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Besides that you don't want to use `Thread.sleep` or something similiar. There are lot of android specific solutions for that. In this case you might want to use a `Handler` with `postDelayed`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem comes from here:

```
 getData();
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Thread(new Runnable() { // <-- here
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while (true) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(60000);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                            if (isRunning) {
                                getData();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Even though you use `runOnUiThread` for the first thread, but you create another thread inside it and this new thread has no access to views.

But I should say that I think your approach is very bad. You can easily use [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer) for your code like this:

```
new Timer(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getDate();
    }
}, 0, 60000).start();
```

and change:

```
mainExplore_progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to

```
mainExplore_progressBar.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mainExplore_progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**Update**:
you can use:

```
new Timer(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            getData();
                        }
                    });
    }
}, 0, 60000).start();
```

too and leave `getData()` method unchanged.